# How to change order inside foreach using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a created a for each loop to load all the script files from my build folder dynamically in the footer with for development and production mode. This way I don't need to manually replace the script files.

But I have a problem, I don't know how to change the order of the files to a specific order.

It should be: Runtime, Vendors, Main.

This is my PHP code:

```
// First check if "JS" folder exist to prevent errors.
if(is_dir(THEME_DIR_ASSETS . '/js')) {
    // Enqueue all scripts.
    function nm_enqueue_scripts() {
    $directoryJS = new DirectoryIterator(THEME_DIR_ASSETS . '/js');

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array(), null, false);

        foreach ($directoryJS as $file) {
            if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'js') {
            $fullName = basename($file);
            $name = substr(basename($fullName), 0, strpos(basename($fullName), '.'));

            wp_enqueue_script($name, THEME_DIR_JS . '/' . $fullName, $name, null, true);
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nm_enqueue_scripts');
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the dependencies of each file to be able to enqueue them in an order you want.
So in the $directoryJS data, you can set dependencies of each script so that it looks like this:

```
$directoryJS = [
[
'script_name' => 'some-name' 
'script_url' => 'path to script',
'deps' => [ 'other-file-name']
],
[
'script_name' => 'other-file-name' 
'script_url' => 'path to other script',
'deps' => [ ]
]
]
```

In the foreach statement the enqueue script function will look like this:
`wp_enqueue_script($script_name, THEME_DIR_JS . '/' . $fullName, $deps, '', true);`.

In this case WP will enqueue 'other-file-name' script before 'some-name' script.

Comment: Thanks. I am using it like this for months no issues at all. It works just perfectly fine. But the problem was only ordering. But If it can be done no big issue.